# Is this expression "he is a man who unified many different kinds of culture" correct?

Tags: expression-choice

There is a man. He used to live in many different country learn different kind of philosophy like Western and Eastern philosophy. He also used to live with very poor people and with very rich people as well. I call him

> he is a man who unified many different kinds of culture

Is it ok to say like that.

Or can we say:

> he is a man who synthesized many different kinds of culture
>
> he is a man who has many different kinds of culture in him
>
> he is a man of different kinds of culture
>
> he is a man with different kinds of culture

Answer (score 2):

This man is **Cosmopolitan**.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cosmopolitan ...

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> He is a man of many cultures.

*unified* is not right -- it means that he caused the cultures, or the people in those cultures, to be combined.

*synthesized* means to make something new.

*of different kinds of culture* and *with different kinds of culture* express what you want, but they're just not common phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I will proceed on the assumption that OP intends, not to say that the man in question united many cultures, but that he was able to amalgamate or incorporate meaningful aspects of diverse cultures within himself.

He is a man who (has) **amalgamated** / **incorporated** many different kinds of culture (*within himself / his person*)

> [**amalgamate**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=amalgamated+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=amalgamated+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.7.3656356...........0.PpdovF7zP7E&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: past tense: **amalgamated**; past participle: amalgamated
>
> combine or unite to form one organization or structure. “he *amalgamated* his company with another”; (Google)
>
> [**incorporated**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorporate) *verb*:
>
> **1a**: to unite or work into something already existent so as to form an indistinguishable whole
>
> **1b**: to blend or combine thoroughly. (Merriam-Webster *online*)